# Move from simple web project to netbeans web project

Tags: java, web-services, maven, netbeans

I have a simple web project containing a RESTful Web Service. It works fine.
Now, I'm trying to migrate to a Maven web project. I'm using Netbeans.

What I did is:

-I created a new Maven Web Project

-I replaced the context.xml from the maven project with the one from the non maven project

-I copied all the packages/classes without modifying anything (I even did some diff between them, nothing is changed)

-I deployed the maven project

The RESTful Web Service doesn't seem to work (or maybe it works, but something is changed in its path?).
The index.html is called properly and I can see the start page (I have a html graphical interface). But every call to the web service returns 404 Not Found.

So, just to be sure I'm not missing anything, I created a new Maven Web Project from scratch. I created a new dummy web service (right click on project -> New Restful Web Services from Patterns). I put 'return "Hello!";' as the action for the get method, I deployed the project and I tried calling it. It doesn't work (I get the 404 error). Also, right click on the resource in Netbeans and Test Resource Uri doesn't work, but this doesn't work for the non maven project either, so maybe it's ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly because the context path contains SNAPSHOT version. Check the war. Open the Files window Window->Files. Find the war file. The name of that will be the context root. If this is the problem, you can change the war output name by adding `<finalName>` element to the `<build>` element. I usually go with `${project.artifactId}` as the final name, which is most of the time the project name

Comment: It's not this, I put the <warName> element in the configuration of the maven-war-plugin, but it doesn't work... The index.html loads ok and the context is the right one (without SNAPSHOT).